# How can i capture street value from Lightning:inputAddress when have multiple lines?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am getting address info from a external system in below format:

```
"street1":"",
"street2":"",
"street3":"",
"city":"",
"state":"",
"country":""
```

which i am storing in a map attribute like below:

```
<aura:attribute name="address" type="map" default="{street1:"",street2:"",street3:"",city:"",state:"",country:""}" />
```

and i am setting the value like below:

```
<lightning:inputAddress
            addressLabel="Address"
            streetLabel="Street"
            cityLabel="City"
            countryLabel="Country"
            provinceLabel="Province"
            postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
            street="{! v.address.street1 +'\n'+v.address.street2+'\n'+v.address.street3}"
            city="San Francisco"
            country="US"
            province="CA"
            postalCode="94105"
        />
```

now, i am able to see the value in multiple lines but when i am trying to update the value, i am not getting the updated values.

Is there a different/easy way to show multiple street lines using inputAddress component other than this format?

**UPDATE**

Added solution that i used as answer.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/262737/edit) to clarify a bit? You are saying you are getting to see the values in multiple lines, but later you want to show it in multiple lines. Seems you already have what you want?

Comment: @JayantDas Just updated. I was not getting the updated values.

Comment: So is your question around not being able to get updated values or not being able to show in multiple lines? If its around update, how are you updating the values?

Comment: @JayantDas i wanted to ask if there's any other way to implement this rather than how i am doing it now. when i update the street value and go to next screen which is a summary section i am not seeing updated value but just the value i got from external system.

Comment: This is based on the assumption that you are fetching the value on your summary screen most likely using the attribute `v.address`. If yes, then you will need to ensure that whenever you are navigating from one screen to other, the attribute `v.address` is updated with the contents that you have entered in the previous screen. For anything else, you will need to provide more code here for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: i think your issue with Map type Attribute, you can not get or set values from Map in Lightning component Html. try to use Object type instead of Map for street attribute.

Comment: @sdandamud1 Thank you for that info, i have noted to self as a technical debt if that's the case and for now instead of using three streets in the Map i using only one and passing the concatenated value into it.

Comment: can you please update your question with work around solution for helping others.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced street1, street2, street3 from Map with street

```
<aura:attribute name="address" type="map" default="{street:"",city:"",state:"",country:""}" />
```

and passing the concatenated value (street = street1+'\n'+street2+'\n'+street3) in the controller after getting those from the external system.